# What is the general survey of Reformation era approaches to Scripture that dismissed troublesome passages?

Tags: scriptures, reformation

In an article entitled, [Bottoms Up! The meaning of “use a little wine…” (1 Tim 5:23)](https://orthodoxchristiantheology.com/2016/05/21/bottoms-up-the-meaning-of-use-a-little-wine-1-tim-523/) at the *Orthodox Christian Theology* website,  the following comment is made:

> John Calvin, though not taking this view himself, speaks of how other
> interpreters thought that the passage was not inspired as it appears
> irrelevant to the immediate context:
>
> “No longer drink water.” There are some who conjecture that this
> sentence, which breaks off the train of thought, was not written by
> Paul. …[I]t is possible that what had been formerly written in the
> margin of the Epistle afterwards.

That quote from Calvin is a bit shocking to me, as it appears that there was kind of a smorgasbord approach to the Bible during the time of the Reformation that I was not aware of. Unfortunately, the author of the article does not give a reference. However, after a bit of internet exploring, I found the original primary source for the quote [here.](https://books.google.com/books?id=9gxXAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=There%20are%20some%20who%20conjecture%20that%20this%20sentence,%20which%20breaks%20off%20the%20train%20of%20thought,%20was%20not%20written%20by%20Paul&source=bl&ots=x5OdU1bzQz&sig=ACfU3U01gHmJyV0dCMdGLjU_DjPLMaA6Tw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUtP24p_L6AhXBFzQIHWj0A4IQ6AF6BAgeEAI#v=onepage&q=There%20are%20some%20who%20conjecture%20that%20this%20sentence%2C%20which%20breaks%20off%20the%20train%20of%20thought%2C%20was%20not%20written%20by%20Paul&f=false)

Are there any examples of 16th & 17th century Reformation era approaches to Scripture (Protestant or Catholic) that has relied upon form criticism to dismiss troublesome passages. or even entire books of the canonical Bible, to make a theological case?

Comment: The linked article does not give any reference for John Calvin's remark. [The Biblehub - John Calvin Commentary](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/calvin/1_timothy/5.htm) has no such remark for the verse. It remains to be properly documented (reliably) that John Calvin ever uttered the statement. This detail requires to be clarified _first_ before pursuing the subject. A 'general survey' of 'Reformation era' 'approaches' would be a very wide question, possibly beyond the scope of this website.

Comment: Nigel, I found the primary source reference and put the link in my post. As for the question being too wide, I limited it to just the 16th & 17th centuries. It is one thing to have disputed books (such as Luther rejecting James, etc.). But it is something else to pick and choose, what is and is not a textual interpolation, based upon just content criticism. It might be an embarrassing reality, in my mind. But to close a post on that basis seems a bit like having a cancel culture approach to doing Christian research.

Comment: Not a bad question but, in my mind, impossible to fully answer.  I would suppose that every theological system, created by men and applied to scripture, is liable to and guilty of just such dismissal of passages that trouble it.  This is the danger inherent in theology, that it is tempted to sacrifice Scripture in order to preserve itself.  For instance, I have heard it argued by those whose theology includes teetotaling, regarding the wedding at Cana, that the wine in those days had so little alcohol as to be considered mere grape juice...therefore Jesus didn't *really* make wine.

Comment: @MikeBorden, What is fascinating is how the Tübingen School theologian, David Friedrich Strauss, rejected the "account of the wedding of Cana as a latter interpolation on the score that that such enjoyment, in his opinion, would be utterly unworthy of Jesus, and it would be dangerous for the guests if there were so much wine." (Ylvisaker, The Gospels: Synopsis, Harmony, Explanatory Notes, p. 136)

Comment: A perfect example.